# Determine path of app prompting for access to macOS keychain item

Tags: macos, keychain

### Context

On macOS, when an app requests permission to access a keychain item, a prompt like this is presented:

[image]

> git-credential-osxkeychain wants to use your confidential information stored in "github.com" in your keychain. The authenticity of "git-credential-osxkeychain" cannot be verified. To allow this, enter the "login" keychain password.

If "Always Allow" is selected (along with the correct password), then the app is added to the access control list for the keychain item:

[image]

### Questions

1. The prompt presents no path information for me to determine which app is asking permission—only the name. **How can I unambiguously determine the full path of the app requesting access in the prompt before making a selection?**

   I recognize these ways to infer which one it is:

   - Check the list of running processes (e.g. in Activity Monitor). But there could be multiple by that name.
   - Search for all instances of files by that name on my device (e.g. `sudo find / -name "git-credential-osxkeychain"`). But there could be multiple matches for that file name.

   However, these methods do not satisfy the question.
2. **How can I determine the path for each of the items in the access control list?** There is no context menu (right-click) for the app names, and double-clicking them also does nothing.

---

Comment: Aside: I know which apps these two are—this is a controlled scenario in order to provide an example.

Comment: You can't. That's why there is the warning. A signed app (where authenticity can be verified) provides assurance and traceability.

Comment: @schroeder Can you elaborate more on that? A simple "you can't" without referential support is not a helpful comment. I see no mention of "traceability", and I have no idea what "authenticity" means in this context, but it's pretty hard for me to believe that macOS has no idea of the path for a process that is requesting keychain access.

Comment: The path can only be relied upon if the process is legitimate and playing by the rules. A malicious app or a process that has taken over something legitimate can obfuscate the path. Therefore there is not much use in tracing the path. If the process is trustworthy, you can trace it using the methods you mention (and the path, ultimately doesn't matter).

Comment: If all you are talking about is tracing *any* process in macOS, then this is no longer a security question but a macOS internals question (and off-topic here).

Comment: @schroeder You said: "A signed app (where authenticity can be verified) provides assurance and traceability." Can you provide an example of a signed app requesting access to a keychain item, where the prompt provides information about the absolute path of the app?

Comment: It doesn't provide the path. Because it is unnecessary. As I said, the path is either unreliable, if the process is malicious, or unnecessary if signed, since if there are multiple instances of the process, it doesn't matter, since the code is trusted and every instance is the same.

Comment: And signed apps would not cause this prompt (as the prompt indicates)

Comment: So, if you just want to trace processes (as it now appears is the core of your question) this is not a security question but a macOS internals question.

Comment: And since the previous version of this question was not tackled here, I'll migrate this for you.